# Which SQL clause should I use?

Tags: sql, pivot, firebird

I have a table like this in Firebird:

```
+-----------+----+------+
|vehiclename|oil |volume|
+-----------+----+------+
|v1         |oil1|12    |
+-----------+----+------+
|v2         |oil2|26    |
+-----------+----+------+
|v3         |oil1|45    |
+-----------+----+------+
|v1         |oil2|78    |
+-----------+----+------+
|v2         |oil3|95    |
+-----------+----+------+
```

and I want that table as

```
+-----------+----+----+----+
|vehiclename|oil1|oil2|oil3|
+-----------+----+----+----+
|v1         |12  |78  |0   |
+-----------+----+----+----+
|v2         |0   |26  |95  |
+-----------+----+----+----+
|v3         |45  |0   |0   |
+-----------+----+----+----+
```

I've tried using exists clause in case statement but no result.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select vehiclename, 
       sum(case when oil = 'oil1' then volume end) as oil_1,
       sum(case when oil = 'oil2' then volume end) as oil_2,
       sum(case when oil = 'oil3' then volume end) as oil_3
from the_table
group by vehiclename
order by vehiclename;
```

If new oil types are added, you need to add one `CASE` statement for each value that can show up in the `oil` column.

If you need an automatic way of doing that, you will need to use dynamic SQL where you first retrieve the distinct values for the `oil` column and then create a SQL statement following the pattern in the above solution. Then run that dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: but will this work for more than oil3?

Comment: Thanks awfully! it works !! only not oil, it should be volume ;)

Comment: @kudra: thanks, corrected (copy & paste error)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT vehiclename,
sum(CASE WHEN oil = 'oil1' THEN volume END) AS oil1,
sum(CASE WHEN oil = 'oil2' THEN volume END) AS oil2,
sum(CASE WHEN oil = 'oil3' THEN volume END) AS oil3
FROM test
GROUP BY vehiclename;
```

[SQL Fiddle [MySQL version]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdf03/5)

Comment: Firebird does not support the (non-standard) `ifnull` function.

Comment: I did not notice "firebird"..

Comment: @kwelsan: Kudra did, in the question tags ;)

Comment: I noticed after @a_horse_with_no_name comment.. Well I mentioned MySQL in the answer.. I hope it will be helpful for someone..